# Internet Explorer 8 does not show loading of a page ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

When I open a site for the first time it is loaded nicely but once it is loaded and I click on any of the links on the page the issue appears.

Internet Explorer 8 does not show loading of a page, it takes me suddenly after several seconds to the clicked page once that page is fully loaded. This happens to everyone who opens our site with IE8.

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: is it working in any other version of IE??

Comment: Yes, it does, and this only happens on native ie8, not in ie9 set to compatability mode.

Comment: check for invalid html, unclosed tags and the like. Sometimes browsers render as the read, sometimes they can't figure out your intention until they read the whole document and think about it for while.

Comment: check if there are any console error ..try to debug it in IE browser using debugger tools...do you have any link or any specific code base to this issue?

Comment: No console errors. Did a html validation and it was successful. To correct myself, when I click on a link, the ie top right icon spins a little bit and nothing happens, and then after a few seconds I am taken to that page.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by nivo slider(jquery plugin). Do not know what it was, but I had 2.4 version and when I switched to 3.1 the issue was fixed.